# Flutter APK generation error in android studio

Tags: android, ios, flutter, apk

C:\Android\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Compiler message:

package:radiojesussauve/main.dart: Error: No 'main' method found.
Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Android\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\Android\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           12.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Error: No 'main' method found. Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.

Comment: Please explain you situation well, providing just errors will not do the trick